# name already exists regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

In my react application I have to show an error if an user name already exists.

```
const regex = '(?:' + availableNames.join('|') + ')';

<div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">

    <input className="mdl-textfield__input" pattern={regex} autoFocus/>

    <label className="mdl-textfield__label" htmlFor="inp-1">User name</label>
    <span className="mdl-textfield__error" >Name already exists</span>
</div>
```

I have started with the following expression `(?:alex|max|sam)` and I know that this allows the user only to input alex, max or sam.

But I can't manage to negate the expression.
I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try something like this with negative lookahead

```
^((?!\b(alex|max|sam)\b).)*$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!\b(alex|max|sam)\b)` - Do not match any word of these words `alex, sam, max`
- `$` - End of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/AUCrBw/1/)